# Android RelativeLayout : positionning in bottom right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

As you can see on the attached screenshot, i have a problem to set the position of my relativeLayout and associated textview on the bottom right of each item of list.

Once the text is so long and take 2 lines, my textview in Relativelayout is cut..

How can i fix this ?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gris_clair"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/blanc" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/allannonces_image"
            android:layout_width="83dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/allannonces_titre"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/allannonces_prix"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/allannonces_categorie"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bordertextview"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="7dp"
                    android:text="TextView" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but have you changed the RelativeLayout to FrameLayout, then add `android:layout_gravity="right"` to your TextView?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd very much simplify your layout design.

Note that this layout not only **solves your issue**, but also **optimizes** the original design.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffff"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/allannonces_image"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/allannonces_titre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/allannonces_image"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="15sp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/allannonces_prix"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/allannonces_titre"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/allannonces_image"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="15sp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/allannonces_categorie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#fddd"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:text="TextView"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please not home many layouts less are in this design.
This will improve the overall performances.

Note that, since I didn't have the colors, I hardcoded the white color on the container and the grey color on the category TextView.

Comment: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" `  gr8

Answer (score 0):

Not only minLines but also give lines

```
           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/allannonces_titre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:lines="2"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in the RelativeLayout that holds that problematic textview of yours to  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.

That should solve your problem...